# Images and slideshow is not displaying in my magento store

Tags: image, magento, caching

i installed "call for price" extension in my website. After installation it automatically cleared all the cache. Now slideshow and thumbnails of products are not showing in site even though i uploaded them again. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to rebuild/regenerate the cache

```
System > Cache Management
```

and then click "Flush Catalog Image Cache"

Comment: i'm trying to regenerate the cache but i couldn't plz help to regenerate. All my product images are also not coming.